# Jetty Maven Plugin

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-jetty-plugin

Has Jetty been completely migrated over to Eclipse yet?

I am using the Maven 2 plugin for Jetty version 7, 20091125.

Just recently, I am getting session manager issues that I never had come up before (no session manager configured).  The standalone instance is running the Eclipse version of Jetty, but the same version, 20091125.

Is anyone else having these issues with the Jetty plugin presently?  What other application servers to you deploy to that have a plugin for quick deployment / testing?

Walter

Comment: BTW, the maven plugin artifact id for jetty 7 is `jetty-maven-plugin` now. No, no, this is not confusing >:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if Jetty 7 is considered as "stable" (see [**About**](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/about.php)), it is far from being as "mature" as Jetty 6 especially after the *significant reorganization of the packaging and jars* that happened in Jetty 7.

This is even more true for the new maven plugin in my opinion - see for example [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215550/mavens-jetty-plugin-ssl-configuration-issue) - and I expect more problems to come since some classes are still in `org.mortbay.jetty` (tell me why). All these changes make it hard to find your way and to find accurate information...

So I agree with @bmargulies here: unless you really need JSP 2.1 or some of the [new features](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-dev/msg00294.html) of Jetty 7, better stick with Jetty 6 (not even to mention that I find this new jetty cumbersome with all its modules).

Comment: Good point, I'm all for the latest and greatest stuff, but some issues some up every now and again making it hard to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I stick with jetty 6. Every time I try version 7 I feel as if I've just walked off ... a jetty.