# Enabling SSL(TLS) for Jetty in Ubuntu Oneiric

Tags: ubuntu, jetty, ssl

I'm using Ubuntu Oneiric Ocelot, which includes in its repos the Jetty 6.1.24 package. It works very well, but I'm having trouble trying to configure it for SSL. I've changed the jetty*.xml files and nothing, not even an error pointing to an SSL issue. I've come as far as creating a keystore (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008837/configure-ssl-on-jetty)), restart but it doesn't work with SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it appears like you have not uncommented the line for `etc/jetty-ssl.xml` in `$JETTY_HOME/start.ini`. Do that, and restart Jetty.