# java keytool giving "final block not properly padded"

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

Per [step 3b of this Jetty guide for using Keytool and OpenSSL, last step](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How+to+configure+SSL), I'm doing the command:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore jetty.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore
```

When I run the command, I get:  `keytool error: java.io.IOException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded`

Do you know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, I had done some of the steps using Windows openSSL that I downloaded, and other steps using the openSSL already existing on the CentOs6 box.   When I did all the steps on the CentOs/linux box, the error went away.

Secondary perhaps helful note linux openSSL and Godaddy, note when you begin the "create CSR" process, use 2048 in generating the site.key, namely:

openssl genrsa -des3 -out site.key 2048

----------------- update ------------------

I think this error is instead related to a password problem I made in the steps.

After one does:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey jetty.key -in cert-chain.txt -out jetty.pkcs12
```

the tool prompts, Enter Export Password:

This password entered, must then be used in the next step, the one I did was:

```
java -classpath jetty-util-6.1.19.jar:jetty-6.1.19.jar org.mortbay.jetty.security.PKCS12Import jetty.pkcs12 keystore
```

however per [this documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How+to+configure+SSL) that step may apparently equally be:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore jetty.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore
```

Comment: You might as well avoid the conversion and use `PKCS12` as the `keystoreType` in Jetty.

Answer (score 6):

I also came across a similar issue. I realized finally that the destination keystore had a key password also specified. So I had to use an extra argument 'destkeypass' to import the keys successfully.

Comment: This was the reason in my case! Thnx. (keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -destkeypass passphrase -deststoretype JKS)