# What causes keytool error "Failed to decrypt safe contents entry"?

Tags: java, openssl, keytool, pkcs#12, jks

I am trying to convert a standard PKCS #12 (.p12) key store into a Java JKS key store with this command:

`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -deststoretype JKS -destkeystore keystore.jks`

It is failing with:

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like your PCKS#12 keystore is corrupt. Can you verify it with `openssl pkcs12 ...`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The pkcs12 keystore was corrupt indeed.

Answer (score 51):

Sometimes this error is symptomatic of using an incorrect password for the p12 key.

Comment: The pkcs12 keystore type doesn't differentiate between keypass and storepass. So in my case I just had to use the storepass (and not the keypass) when retrieving the key...

Comment: I used the wrong password because WebSphere is using a different default password than most Java trust stores.

Comment: That's what it was for me. Jesus, took me a while to get this to work.

Answer (score 8):

I've never attempted to do this before, but I did find instructions on google [here](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1283).

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236939/java-keytool-giving-final-block-not-properly-padded) asks a similar question.

**EDIT (Based on comment)**

Here is the full content of the linked reference:

PFX/P12 to JKS (Java KeyStore)

**Question:** How do I move a certificate from IIS / PFX (.p12 file) to a JKS (Java KeyStore)?

**Answer:** keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore PFX_P12_FILE_NAME -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcstorepass PFX_P12_FILE -srcalias SOURCE_ALIAS -destkeystore KEYSTORE_FILE -deststoretype jks -deststorepass PASSWORD -destalias ALIAS_NAME

**Note:** To find the srcalias, list the contents of the PFX/P12 file:

keytool -v -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore PFX_P12_FILE > FILENAME.TXT As this writes the output of the command to a file with the name of FILENAME.TXT.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem i entered the password manually and problem got resolved

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue when i was trying to export certs as pfx from JKS.It worked when i excluded deststorepass attribute in keytool command & gave the destination store password at runtime.

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore Keystore.jks -destkeystore dv163.pfx -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -srcalias alias1-destalias alias1

Enter destination keystore password:

Re-enter new password:

Enter source keystore password:

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue today(BadPaddingException). It seems keytool had a problem with certain characters in the password. I solved it by adding double-quotes around the password.

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore PFX_P12_FILE_NAME -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcstorepass "PFX_P12_FILE" -srcalias SOURCE_ALIAS -destkeystore KEYSTORE_FILE -deststoretype jks -deststorepass "PASSWORD" -destalias ALIAS_NAME

Answer (score 2):

I did this command (opposite to yours) to export a private key to PKCS12 from a JKS:

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore DemoIdentity.jks -srcstoretype JKS -destkeystore demoidentity.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12

If I left off the seemingly redundant "-srcstoretype JKS", the generated demoidentity.p12 file gave me the same error when I tried to list the details in keytool even though the above command accepted the passwords and generated a file seemingly correctly!

For your issue, perhaps you did something similar when generating keystore.p12.

Comment: I think you're on to something. Probably keytool assume the original key is something else.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was somewhat unique. When I tested locally in my dev environment, it seemed to work fine. However, when i deployed to our live environments, it was giving the root error `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException:`

After some debugging it turned out due to the jdk i was using in my docker image. It seems to me some jdks (e.g., some 1.8 packages) aren't compatible. With some tests I found a jdk (11.0.21) that worked with it. If you've attempted all the options and nothing has worked, then try this option and check if its the jdk.

Answer (score 0):

From my side I forget to check language when you type password :)[image]

Answer (score 0):

simply type the correct password on the build signed APK wizard form.
( it worked with me on android studio 4.2 canary 15++)

As I came to find out, when you change app on said wizard, spite the password remains, somehow it does not sign correctly, so you need to clear the password and type it again.

Answer (score 0):

Almost lost my mind around it, if you generate the password, make sure it's in ASCII and not include chars other than letters, number and symbols. UTF-8 special chars might broke it.

Comment: ANSI? Do you mean ASCII?

Comment: fixed it. thank you for point it out

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because of the password contains some special characters at the start or at the end (it's correct but not supported), just make sure you use normal words with numbers if it didn't work for your upload key

```
Cause: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
```