# (SoapUI) An error occurred (Probably bad PKCS12 password: java.io.IOException...)

Tags: jenkins, ssl-certificate, soapui

I set SSL Keystore and password programmatically, but I get error message. Password is correct

```
ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [Probably bad PKCS12 password: java.io.IOException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded], see error log for details
org.apache.commons.ssl.ProbablyBadPasswordException: Probably bad PKCS12 password: java.io.IOException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyStoreBuilder.tryJKS(KeyStoreBuilder.java:510)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyStoreBuilder.parse(KeyStoreBuilder.java:392)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyStoreBuilder.build(KeyStoreBuilder.java:112)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyMaterial.<init>(KeyMaterial.java:179)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyMaterial.<init>(KeyMaterial.java:170)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyMaterial.<init>(KeyMaterial.java:160)
```

Comment: Please see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338543/what-causes-keytool-error-failed-to-decrypt-safe-contents-entry) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to set keystore_password first, than keystore.