# jetty maven dependencies

Tags: ssl, maven, jetty

We are using the maven Jetty plugin for development. 
i always used

```
 <jetty.version>7.2.2.v20101205</jetty.version>
```

and

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        <configuration>...</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now i wanted to add an SSL connector and tried to add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-ssl</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This doesn't work, the dependency was not found. Now i see that jetty moved to eclipse. 
But i couldn't find any jetty-ssl dependency at eclipse repository. Now i am lost.
It seems to me that everything is messed up. I have no clue where to search for my dependencies which i want to include in my POM.

So: Where is the "official" maven jetty repository for version 7.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what worked for me: update the connector implementation classes to use the eclipse names, then remove the extra dependency section.  So, your configuration section should look like this:

```
<configuration>
  <connectors>
    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <port>8080</port>
    </connector>
    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector">
        <port>8443</port>
        <keystore>jetty-ssl.keystore</keystore>
        <password>mypassword</password>
        <keyPassword>mypassword</keyPassword>
    </connector>
  </connectors>
...
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty-ssl) you can see the jetty-ssl dependency has a different version number for mortbay. And from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215550/mavens-jetty-plugin-ssl-configuration-issue/5874640#5874640) it seems you don't need the jetty-ssl depdency for the version on eclipse. I believe that eclipse is now the official version.

Comment: You are as clueless as i am, arent' you? :-) I love jetty but at the moment everything is messed up.